# Find if systime lies between two times -oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

**UPDATE**

Basically ,i am trying to create a trigger which restricts any changes to table b/w 9 p.m and 9 a.m .Here is the sample .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER courses_biud
before insert or update or delete 
on courses 
begin
if to_char(sysdate,'hh24') between **{9 p.m and 9.am}** Then 
...
end ;
```

Comment: Give sample which you have tried till yet.

Comment: `select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) from dual;
select to_number(to_char(to_date(2100,'hh24MI'),'HH24')));` Just getting confused with all this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_char(sysdate,'hh24') || ' is in the timeframe'  as result
from dual
where to_char(sysdate,'hh24') > 21
or to_char(sysdate,'hh24') < 9
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, how is `to_char(sysdate,'hh24') < 9` 9am the next day?

Comment: sysdate is always right now..  so this question is 'is right now after 9pm or before 9 am'?

Comment: From OP: `This is what i want to achieve *9pm < sysdate < 9am(next day) *`

Comment: it would be a slightly different question if you want to check an arbitrary date - but that's not in the original question

Comment: This will be 9am on the current day @Randy. You mean sysdate + 1, I think.